# Reading Domain User's Emails Using GSuite API

Tags: python, gmail-api, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I want to read my user's emails using Gmail API. I don't want to use GAM or any other backup tool. Gmail provides an option of user delegation but individual users have to assign a delegated user which is not possible in my case.
How I can natively read my domain user's email from admin account using Gmail API or Admin SDK.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Whoever downvote the post should at least add a comment saying why he did that. Posting questions in here means that the author really needs help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do domain-wide delegation for workaround approach. See the links below for more information about domain-wide delegation, how it works and its step by step settings in admin console:

**Reference for more information about domain-wide delegation and its step by step setting:**
https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en

**Actual case that is related to domain-wide delegation for Gmail:**

[Gmail API domain-wide delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39189523/gmail-api-domain-wide-delegation)