# Gmail API forwardingAs

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I'm curious if it's possible to gain access to the Gmail settings of all users within a domain once a user with Admin access authenticates. I know using the Admin SDK, you have access to user settings, however, I'd like to setup email forwarding and it doesn't seem like it's possible without each user authenticating.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39297532/5832311). Before you can call the Gmail API you need to use the service account "JWT flow" in your code to retrieve an OAuth2 credential for the Gmail user you want to access. Here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests). You may also check this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786709/gmail-api-super-admin-access-other-users-accounts-via-api).